# Mysql Cross Join Pagination and performance

Tags: mysql, join, pagination

I have a simple attendance report to make. pretty basic one.
i have three tables "employees" , "transaction", "calendar"

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
 `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmployeeID` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `EmployeeID` (`EmployeeID`),
  CONSTRAINT `transaction_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `datefield` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with the following select query

```
SELECT
  calendar.datefield,
  `e`.`name`,
  IF( `t`.`Date` IS NULL, 'ABSENT', 'PRESENT' ) as Status
FROM calendar
CROSS JOIN `employee` as `e`
LEFT JOIN `transaction` as `t` ON DATE(`t`.`Date`) = calendar.datefield AND `e`.`ID` = `t`.`EmployeeID`
WHERE
    calendar.datefield BETWEEN '2015-04-30' AND '2015-05-31'    
GROUP BY `e`.`ID`, DATE( calendar.datefield )
ORDER BY `e`.`ID`, calendar.datefield
```

you can find the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/710775/1

now its working perfectly, but with records less than 10,000.
in both tables transactions and employee.
the problem comes with more than 50K records, this query will take up  15 secs to complete, on Mysql 5.1 InnoDB, linux server.
if I add the

```
LIMIT M,N
```

it doesnt help. Mysql is getting all the records and then getting the offset only.

so my question is: how can I make this simple query to perform even faster on  pagination?
do i have to re-structure my cross join?

Comment: What does `explain select...` says ? Add that to the question.

Comment: In addition I could see you are using `date()` function which is not needed. Perhaps try adding the following indexes `alter table transaction add index Date_idx(Date);
alter table calendar add index datefield_idx(datefield);` and then by the following query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ae98/4, take a backup of the tables before applying the indexes.

Comment: I doubt that you can do much with the current structure,there is simply no way to add the calendar table without a cross join.

Comment: I added  the indexing for table calendar, not much of a performance, explain gives me "Using temporary; Using filesort", "Using where; Using index; Using join buffer"

Comment: and there is possible key "PRIMARY,datefield_2,datefield", "EmployeeID"